# Why does the template instantion depth exceed the limit in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I type this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
template <int n, int i = 0>
class show {
public:
    show () {
        if (i % 2) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
            show <n-1, i+1>();
        }else {
            show <n,i+1>();
        }
    }
};

template <int i>
class show <0, i> {};



int main()
{
    show <6>();
}
```

I thought it would write 6 first numbers nondivisible by 2. Instead, I get an error

> fatal error: template instantion exceeds maximum of 100

Why do I get this error if it should instantiate at most 12 instantions?

Comment: You specialize a number which sub-specializes an ever-increasing number. You just reach a fixed number of iterations before the compiler runs out of resources.

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
show () {
   if ( i % 2 )
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

   show<n-(i%2 ? 1 : 0), i+1>();
}
```

Or, if you can use C++17, also with

```
show () {
    if constexpr (i % 2) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        show <n-1, i+1>();
    }else {
        show <n,i+1>();
    }
}
```

The problem with your code

```
show () {
    if (i % 2) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        show <n-1, i+1>();
    }else {
        show <n,i+1>();
    }
}
```

is that isn't important if `i % 2` is true or false: both `show`s, `show<n-1, i+1>` and `show<n, i+1>`, are implemented. So a lot of unnecessary `show`s are implemented and the maximum number of template instantiation is reached.

C++17 introduce `if constexpr` exactly to avoid this sort of problems.

Pre C++17, you can solve with

```
show<n-(i%2 ? 1 : 0), i+1>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function `show()`:

```
show () {
    if (i % 2) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        show <n-1, i+1>();
    }else {
        show <n,i+1>();
    }
}
```

class template `show` is instantiated in both parts of `if` clause.

You need to switch to `if constexpr` to do a single proper instantation:

```
show () {
    if constexpr (i % 2) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        show <n-1, i+1>();
    }else {
        show <n,i+1>();
    }
}
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://godbolt.org/g/TE9Rqs)

Answer (score 1):

To see what's going on, let's try to "inline" the instantiation of the simpler expression `show<1>()`:

In the first recursion level, this is what we will get:

```
if (0 % 2) {
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
    show <0,1>(); // <-- this will instantiate to a no-op.
} else {
    show <1,1>();
}
```

This is the second:

```
if (0 % 2) {
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
} else {
    show <1,1>(); // <-- now this will instantiate
}
```

Third:

```
if (0 % 2) {
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
} else {
    if (1 % 2) {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
        show <0,1>(); // <-- this will instantiate to a no-op.
    } else {
        show <1,2>();
    }
}
```

Fourth:

```
if (0 % 2) {
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
} else {
    if (1 % 2) {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    } else {
        show <1,2>(); // <-- now this will instantiate
    }
}
```

Fifth:

```
if (0 % 2) {
    std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
} else {
    if (1 % 2) {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    } else {
        if (1 % 2) {
            std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
            show <0,2>(); // <-- this will again instantiate to a no-op...
        } else {
            show <1,3>(); // <-- ... and I'm sure you can see where this is going.
        }
    }
}
```

This exemplifies what the other answers already pointed out: Templates are code generators. This means that if the compiler reaches a template, it will always generate code from that template, regardless of any logic your program has before reaching it.

This is what `if constexpr` prevents. If the expression at an `if constexpr` evaluates to a falsy value, the compiler will ignore any code that's inside said `if constexpr` block.

If you don't have a C++17 compiler, you can achieve the same results using SFINAE.